# Rexroth Indramat CLM 1.3, how to execute command

Tags: control

I have to execute the command:

CLA Clear Axis (Absolute Encoder Value)

`E 0170 CLA`
`2`

To be honest I don't know how the CLM works yet.
Need to fix some problem first.
I get the absolute encoder error so I want to reset the value in a buffer first
because it doesn't change. It is stuck on some high value.
I assumed the clm runs all the commands after restart but the buffer stays full after the restart.